# str_replace doesn't replace comma with dot

Tags: php

I use str_replace but doesn't change the comma into a dot.

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost"; 
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "grades";


if(isset($_GET["herolist"]) && isset($_GET["grade"]) && isset($_GET["weight"])){
    $subject = $_GET["herolist"];
    $grade = $_GET["grade"];
    $weight = $_GET["weight"];
    str_replace(',', '.', $grade);
    echo $grade;
}
?>
```

I am really confused why it doesn't work because everywhere I look I see this option to replace a comma with a dot.

Can someone maybe help me?

Thanks!

Comment: `$grade = str_replace(',', '.', $grade);` You've to assign a variable, str_replace is returning a value, not taking $grade as a reference.

Comment: see @C.Malet comment. I just downvotes this as this is really, really basic. Please put more effort into solving an issue yourself.

Comment: Before posting, please read relevant documentation such as http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php for example.

Comment: I know, I feel like a noob. Thanks!

Comment: `function mystr_replace($from, $to, &$value) { $value = str_replace(',', '.', $value); } mystr_replace(',', '.', $grade); echo $grade;`

Comment: Well, I don't understand why this is downvoted so much, for no good reason, he is learning, it is far more better than other questions out here

Comment: @MrAlien - True! I've seen worse questions from people with rep in the thousands... and I didn't downvote either; but learning that the PHP docs should be the first port of call rather than asking on SO is also a part of learning

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) :

> This function returns a string or an array

So you have to re-assign it:

```
$grade = str_replace(',', '.', $grade);
```